# error when cassandra-cli command executed in ssh

Tags: ssh, sh, cassandra-cli

I have two servers A and B, I have a shell script in serverA which logs into serverB (through ssh) and runs the following command:

```
sh cassandra-cli -h <serverB> -v -f database_import.txt;
```

so when I do this manually, I follow these steps:

```
serverA:~$ ssh serverB
serverB:~$ sh cassandra-cli -h <serverB> -v -f database_import.txt;
```

It works properly when I follow these steps manually but when I automate this process in a shell script by this following line:

```
serverA:~$ssh serverB "sh cassandra-cli -h <serverB> -v -f database_import.txt;"
```

I get this error,

```
cassandra-cli: 46: cassandra-cli: -ea: not found
```

Comment: What is inside the cassandra-cli script? Especially around 46 line.

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko well what ever is in line 46 how come it executed when I executed that command manually and not in the script??

Comment: Could be anything! That is why I am asking.

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko here it is

`$JAVA -ea -cp $CLASSPATH -Xmx256M \
        -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-tools.properties \
        org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain "$@"`

Comment: What happens if you do ``echo "$JAVA"`` through ssh?

Comment: Its empty.. But even if this is the case we cannot justify the problem of it working when executed manually and not by script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as you already pointed out, `$JAVA` is empty through ssh.

This is because `.bashrc` is not sourced when you log in using `ssh`. You can source it like this:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

And your command is going to look like this:

```
ssh serverB ". ~/.bashrc; sh cassandra-cli -h <serverB> -v -f database_import.txt;"
```

You can also try placing this into your [.bash_profile](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html) instead of invoking it manually each time.

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```